# Silverlight UserControl with text field

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I've created a simple UserControl in ExpressionBlend. The UserControl is a ractangle with a TextBlock in it. When i use this UserContol in a Silverlight project, i can not change the text in the textBlock of the control. Should give an acces to the TextBlock before using the Control?

HELP"_

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take some time to read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Your user control should have public properties that map to its features. If you want the users of the control to be able to set the text, create a Text property. The implementation can be as simple as forwarding to the inner TextBox.
Exposing the inner control is not the right way to do it.

Comment: OK...so should I do it like this:

public string PublicProductName
{

    get { return (String)GetValue(this.ProductName.Text); }
    set {

             { SetValue(this.ProductName.Text, value); }

         }

}
??


Is it OK?

Comment: What are GetValue and SetValue in your context ? DependencyObject.GetValue ? If yes, you don't need them. Just return or set ProductName.Text.

Comment: public String PublicProductName
        {
            get { return this.ProductName.Text; }
            set { this.ProductName.Text = PublicProductName.ToString(); }
        }


I think this does not work at all...:(

Comment: And here is how i Use this controll and how i'm trying ot set the content:
<leaf:MainControl Name="firstLeaf" PublicProductName="shdaksflahsdgkfjahsgdkfjhgasdh"></leaf:MainControl>

                </controls:TreeViewItem>

Comment: OK ....i've found the error:) it should not be:
 set { this.ProductName.Text = PublicProductName.ToString()
BUT:
 set { this.ProductName.Text = value}